# Motion graphic software suggestions

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

I'm attempting to find motion graphics software to visually explain complex topics.

Here's an example of what I'm after: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEH_3BPu0As

I've looked at Houdini, After Effects, Boris, etc., but all of those products seem to be overkill for what I'm trying to do.

I'm just looking for a few standard shapes/images (and ability to import my own images) that I can move around and voice over.

(I'm using a PC)

Comment: If you want it as simple as you say why dont you just use photoshop? You can create a timeline and with a few keyframes your shapes are moving

Comment: @JVS Thanks. I'm new to this area, so I'll check it out.

Comment: I would suggest using Adobe Premier or After Effects if you have access to Adobe products.

Comment: I would say mathematica but that may be overkill for you. Maybe flash?

Comment: Based on the software listed, I've made the assumption that you're using Windows. If that is not the case, please feel free to revert my edit

Comment: What you need is presentation software. Look for tutorials on how to do basic animations in Powerpoint, Prezi or similar applications and how to record your presentation with a voiceover.

Comment: I think your sample video can be done with just Powerpoint

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like a software recommendation question.

Answer (score 3):

Edited some time later. Probably a good option for that kind of video is using PowerPoint, which have some transitions that can be used for animation, and also have some built in animation tools.

Libre Office have more rudimentary transitions. But it is also an option because that video have very simple ones.

---

But if you are looking for a more specific animation software:

Some free options I know.

1. Express Animate. http://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/index.html It is easy to use, can export to video and html5 canvas, can animate, rotate, scale, and you can edit the velocity and trajectory with ease in - out nodes. Very lightweight and it is free.
2. Blender http://www.blender.org/, you can do a 2D animation just using a top view for example. There will be plenty of tools you won't use... but it's free.
3. HitFilm Express. A fully functional compositor (Think of after effects) https://hitfilm.com/express
4. Another option, flash like and free: http://www.synfig.org/cms/
5. If you like a free stick figures tool: http://pivotanimator.net/.

And other not too expensive ones.

6. A good payed option is Crazy Talk Animator http://www.reallusion.com/crazytalk/animator/default.aspx it is not expensive, and it is verey flexible.
7. Another is Anime Studio (Now Moho) debut http://my.smithmicro.com/anime-studio-debut-10.html. Probably more specialized than Crazy talk.

In some cases you will need to syinc your voice trial and error, you can use http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ to record.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a Mac, but Keynote has some very basic motion tools that might fit your needs. You can even [record a voiceover](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3699) to your presentation then [export the entire presentation](http://www.ifelix.co.uk/tech/video/v1004.html) as a video file.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I'm using a PC. Does something like this exist for PC users?

Comment: @TomArcher it sounds like you can [record narration and export video of your animated presentation](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/Turn-your-presentation-into-a-video-c140551f-cb37-4818-b5d4-3e30815c3e83?CorrelationId=4449a679-1493-48e0-9e90-5ae0c2e000d6&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) from Powerpoint too.