# program to create simple animations for visualization?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation

I'm looking for a small and light program that allows me to create simple animations for the purpose of visualization. I want to be able to create animations similair to [this](https://youtu.be/pdXyDLsemz8?t=44s).

Usually, I do animations like these in PowerPoint, however it's way too bloated/slow for the simple animations I want to do. I'm looking for a faster alternative that is more focused on creating simple animations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46587/motion-graphic-software-suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I found the difficulty curve of after effects very steep. It's enormously powerful but it's a keyframe based, timeline animation tool. A lot of the really obvious properties are buried in "twirl down" menus.

If you're just looking to import images and move them around, you could try Flinto https://www.flinto.com/ - it's great for very simple animations where you set a start and end state in separate screens, then it tweens the motion for you.

It also has the advantage of really simple interactivity because it's a prototyping tool.

Comment: That would've been great if it wasn't Mac only. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Animation is usually a very heavy thing. There are no programs I can think of that are very light in the way you are describing.

I would suggest checking out Adobe After Effects. You can import images and with a very simple keyframe animation, you can move them. You can download a free demo of After Effects on the [Adobe website](https://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) to get a feel for it.

Check YouTube for tutorials on "Keyframe Animation in After Effects" and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create SVG animations with [CSS, SMIL or Javascript](https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/135-three-ways-animate-svg/). It will be responsive, lightweight and you do not need heavy software to create it, just your browser and any code editor. There are [several javascript libraries](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=svg%20css%20animation%20library) available for free, for example [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/).

Actually you just need the browser if you use an online code editor like [Codepen](https://codepen.io/).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the animations for a video, I really like a lot HitFilm Express. It is a compositor and it is also a video editor.

The animations are done in the compositor. It is similar to After Effects.

https://hitfilm.com/express

If you need simple animations for a webpage, one really lightweight and simple program... also free is Express Animate https://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check [synfig](https://www.synfig.org/) if it suites your needs / expectations